# JavaMelody and Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, java-melody

I have been developing a web app using Spring Boot and Spring Security among other things.

Everything was working well till I integrated with JavaMelody. Now, every REST API call annotated with `@PreAuthorize` is giving a HTTP status `404`.

How can I configure JavaMelody for working with Spring Security? I followed the official guide to integrate JavaMelody in a Spring Boot app (https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/UserGuideAdvanced#spring-boot-app) and so JavaMelody is working, but... I did not find any info about my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Spring Boot to 1.4.1 and now it is working.